# New questions dissapearing

Tags: bug, questions

I've been experiencing a strange thing where I can have X amount of questions (posted from X to Y mins ago), and when I then open a question and I go back to the list of questions, I'm only shown questions from X (usually 7-10) minutes ago.

To Clarify, (this is an' example):

There is 10 Questions:

- Question A - Posted 1 minute ago
- Question B - Posted 2 minute ago
- Question C - Posted 3 minute ago
- Question D - Posted 4 minute ago
- Question E - Posted 5 minute ago
- Question F - Posted 6 minute ago
- Question G - Posted 7 minute ago
- Question H - Posted 8 minute ago
- Question I - Posted 9 minute ago
- Question J - Posted 10 minute ago

I then view Question B, when I then go back to the list of questions, question:

- Question A - Posted 1 minute ago
- Question B - Posted 2 minute ago
- Question C - Posted 3 minute ago
- Question D - Posted 4 minute ago
- Question E - Posted 5 minute ago

Are **gone**, no matter what I do, refreshing, clearing cache, CTRL + F5, try and search the tag again and so on doesn't solve it, question A to - E are "gone".

Only after a random amount of time (sometimes 5 minutes other times 20) do they reappear.

While the questions are gone, I can still see Newer posted questions (the bar with X new questions has been asked), and click it and those appear just fine.

Comment: www.shouldiblamecaching.org ?